# Is listening to singing bowl(Tibetan sound) haram

Tags: halal-haram, music

Salamoe alaykum

Is listening to singing bowl(Tibetan sound) haram or halal? It doesn’t have strings but prophet Mohammed Sallallahu alaihi wa sallam
Said that if you copy from another culture  that you’re one of them,I don’t have knowledge about it and I want to listen to it but I can’t find anything about it and want to know if I can listen to it or not.

Wa allaikum salam

Comment: please write in English

Comment: Edit it to English,sorry forgot it was an English site

Comment: @UmH A singing bowl is rather different from music. It is used for healing/therapy. I used one before I embraced Islam, and am unsure mkyself whether o not they are halaal. I couldn't find anything either way.